# A list of the first and last date of the month based on a year

Tags: php, date, datetime

I want to create a function which outputs a list of the first date of the month and last date of the month based on the year, which is given as an argument.

```
function first_and_last_dates_of_month($year){
//code
}

first_and_last_dates_of_month(2014);
```

I want to have the output somthing like this:

```
2014-01-01
2014-01-31
2014-02-01
2014-02-28
2014-03-01
2014-03-31
2014-04-01
2014-04-30
2014-05-01
2014-05-31
2014-06-01
2014-06-30
2014-07-01
2014-07-31
2014-08-01
2014-08-31
2014-09-01
2014-09-30
2014-10-01
2014-10-31
2014-11-01
2014-11-30
2014-12-01
2014-12-31
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help you:

```
function first_and_last_dates_of_month($year=2014){
    for ($i=1; $i<=12; $i++) {
        $timestamp = strtotime(date("$i/01/y"));
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $first_second = date('Y-m-01', $timestamp);
        echo "<br/>";
        echo $last_second  = date('Y-m-t', $timestamp);
    }
}

first_and_last_dates_of_month(2014);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is also a possibility.

```
$year = date('Y');
$array = array(
    1 =>  ''.$year.'-01-01',
    2 =>  ''.$year.'-01-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 1, $year),
    3 =>  ''.$year.'-02-01',
    4 =>  ''.$year.'-02-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 2, $year),
    5 =>  ''.$year.'-03-01',
    6 =>  ''.$year.'-03-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 3, $year),
    7 =>  ''.$year.'-04-01',
    8 =>  ''.$year.'-04-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 4, $year),
    9 =>  ''.$year.'-05-01',
    10 => ''.$year.'-05-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 5, $year),
    11 => ''.$year.'-06-01',
    12 => ''.$year.'-06-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 6, $year),
    13 => ''.$year.'-07-01',
    14 => ''.$year.'-07-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 7, $year),
    15 => ''.$year.'-08-01',
    16 => ''.$year.'-08-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 8, $year),
    17 => ''.$year.'-09-01',
    18 => ''.$year.'-09-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 9, $year),
    19 => ''.$year.'-10-01',
    20 => ''.$year.'-10-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 10, $year),
    21 => ''.$year.'-11-01',
    22 => ''.$year.'-11-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 11, $year),
    23 => ''.$year.'-12-01',
    24 => ''.$year.'-12-'.cal_days_in_month(CAL_GREGORIAN, 12, $year));
var_dump($array);
```

Comment: whay did you added '' `''.$year.'-01-01'`? Is there any purpose behind that??

Comment: so you can also do it like `$year.'-01-01'` without quotes